# Why Object Types needs Dynamic Memory and Primitive types needs Static memory?

Tags: heap-memory, primitive-types, stack-memory, object-type

I was reading on memory Allocation concepts. where I found a statement saying **Object Types needs Dynamic Memory and Primitive types needs Static memory** they justify it saying **If the requirement is of dynamic memory, it’s allocated on the heap or else it goes on a stack.**

i am not getting the concept why this is so?

Every help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds extremely weird to me. I guess what the authors may have meant is that primitive types will not require memory beyond their constant size while complex entities may need additional memory at runtime according to their state.

Comment: yes exactly thats what they mean

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not 100% complete, but some of this is relevant, and I don't have the rep to simply comment...

The heap sticks around for the life of the program and is much larger (in general), so it may be a design decision that objects (in memory managed languages like C# and Java) are allocated to the heap to not overload stack memory.  Also, stack memory is associated with variable scope (when it can be used) by nature of a stack, and if the memory manager will handle the objects it is more efficient to do it at certain times, versus every time the variable pops off the stack.  Heaps also do not have variable size restrictions, which more realistically accommodates objects, which can be very large depending on what is defined in their class.

Here is a very good explanation of the differences of the two (stack, heap):
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx

Also very good, but more geared toward C:
http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Though neither of those links specifically address WHY for C#.  I'm probably going to get docked for this answer :)

Answer (score -1):

The reason that objects need dynamic memory and primitives need static memory is because primitive types have a predefined size; therefore, they can be placed in the static memory.  Objects size may not be known before run-time, so the memory is allocated dynamically.

Comment: This means Memory was made in concern of these types?

Comment: That's incorrect. Object size is very well known at compile time.

Comment: I guess this depends on programming language

Comment: If you are getting input from the user for instance, how would the compiler know how many bytes the user will enter for a string?

Comment: @rharrison33 this has nothing to do with the object size concept. Object size is inferred from object type which is known at compile time for all types of objects, whether they're primitive or not

Comment: @icepack I'm confused.  What is the difference between my answer and your comment above?

Comment: Well, you write objects size may not be known before run-time; I wrote exactly the opposite...

Comment: Are not objects and complex entities synonyms of each other?

Comment: A. no. B. There is a big difference between entity/object/whatever size and it's requirements for resources (in this case memory).